# kafka streams exception Could not find a public no-argument constructor for org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes$WrapperSerde

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

getting the below error stack trace while working with kafka streams

UPDATE: as per @matthias-j-sax, have implemented my own `Serdes` with default constructor for `WrapperSerde` but still getting the following exceptions

```
org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: stream-thread [streams-request-count-4c239508-6abe-4901-bd56-d53987494770-StreamThread-1] Failed to rebalance.
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.pollRequests (StreamThread.java:836)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce (StreamThread.java:784)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop (StreamThread.java:750)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run (StreamThread.java:720)
Caused by: org.apache.kafka.streams.errors.StreamsException: Failed to configure value serde class myapps.serializer.Serdes$WrapperSerde
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig.defaultValueSerde (StreamsConfig.java:972)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AbstractProcessorContext.<init> (AbstractProcessorContext.java:59)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.<init> (ProcessorContextImpl.java:42)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.<init> (StreamTask.java:136)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread$TaskCreator.createTask (StreamThread.java:405)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread$TaskCreator.createTask (StreamThread.java:369)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread$AbstractTaskCreator.createTasks (StreamThread.java:354)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.addStreamTasks (TaskManager.java:148)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.createTasks (TaskManager.java:107)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread$RebalanceListener.onPartitionsAssigned (StreamThread.java:260)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.onJoinComplete (ConsumerCoordinator.java:259)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.joinGroupIfNeeded (AbstractCoordinator.java:367)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureActiveGroup (AbstractCoordinator.java:316)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.poll (ConsumerCoordinator.java:290)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce (KafkaConsumer.java:1149)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll (KafkaConsumer.java:1115)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.pollRequests (StreamThread.java:827)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce (StreamThread.java:784)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop (StreamThread.java:750)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run (StreamThread.java:720)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at myapps.serializer.Serdes$WrapperSerde.configure (Serdes.java:30)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig.defaultValueSerde (StreamsConfig.java:968)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.AbstractProcessorContext.<init> (AbstractProcessorContext.java:59)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.ProcessorContextImpl.<init> (ProcessorContextImpl.java:42)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamTask.<init> (StreamTask.java:136)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread$TaskCreator.createTask (StreamThread.java:405)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread$TaskCreator.createTask (StreamThread.java:369)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread$AbstractTaskCreator.createTasks (StreamThread.java:354)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.addStreamTasks (TaskManager.java:148)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.TaskManager.createTasks (TaskManager.java:107)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread$RebalanceListener.onPartitionsAssigned (StreamThread.java:260)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.onJoinComplete (ConsumerCoordinator.java:259)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.joinGroupIfNeeded (AbstractCoordinator.java:367)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.AbstractCoordinator.ensureActiveGroup (AbstractCoordinator.java:316)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.internals.ConsumerCoordinator.poll (ConsumerCoordinator.java:290)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.pollOnce (KafkaConsumer.java:1149)
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer.poll (KafkaConsumer.java:1115)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.pollRequests (StreamThread.java:827)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runOnce (StreamThread.java:784)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.runLoop (StreamThread.java:750)
    at org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.internals.StreamThread.run (StreamThread.java:720)
```

Here's my usecase:

I will be getting json responses as input to the stream, I want to count requests whose status codes are not 200. Initially, I went through the documentation of kafka streams in official documentation as well as confluent, then implemented `WordCountDemo` which is working very fine, then I tried to wrote this code, but getting this exception, I am very new to kafka streams, I went through the stack trace, but couldn't understood the context, hence came here for help!!!

Here's my code

`LogCount.java`

```
package myapps;

import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch;

import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serde;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serdes;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.KafkaStreams;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsBuilder;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.StreamsConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.Topology;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.KStream;
import org.apache.kafka.streams.kstream.Produced;
import myapps.serializer.JsonDeserializer;
import myapps.serializer.JsonSerializer;
import myapps.Request;


public class LogCount {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put(StreamsConfig.APPLICATION_ID_CONFIG, "streams-request-count");
        props.put(StreamsConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
        JsonSerializer<Request> requestJsonSerializer = new JsonSerializer<>();
        JsonDeserializer<Request> requestJsonDeserializer = new JsonDeserializer<>(Request.class);
        Serde<Request> requestSerde = Serdes.serdeFrom(requestJsonSerializer, requestJsonDeserializer);
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_KEY_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, Serdes.String().getClass().getName());
        props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, requestSerde.getClass().getName());
        final StreamsBuilder builder = new StreamsBuilder();

        KStream<String, Request> source = builder.stream("streams-requests-input");
        source.filter((k, v) -> v.getHttpStatusCode() != 200)
                .groupByKey()
                .count()
                .toStream()
                .to("streams-requests-output", Produced.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Long()));
        final Topology topology = builder.build();
        final KafkaStreams streams = new KafkaStreams(topology, props);
        final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        System.out.println(topology.describe());
        // attach shutdown handler to catch control-c
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread("streams-shutdown-hook") {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                streams.close();
                latch.countDown();
            }
        });

        try {
            streams.cleanUp();
            streams.start();
            latch.await();
        } catch (Throwable e) {
            System.exit(1);
        }
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

`JsonDeserializer.java`

```
package myapps.serializer;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Deserializer;
import java.util.Map;

public class JsonDeserializer<T> implements Deserializer<T> {

    private Gson gson = new Gson();
    private Class<T> deserializedClass;

    public JsonDeserializer(Class<T> deserializedClass) {
        this.deserializedClass = deserializedClass;
    }

    public JsonDeserializer() {
    }

    @Override
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void configure(Map<String, ?> map, boolean b) {
        if(deserializedClass == null) {
            deserializedClass = (Class<T>) map.get("serializedClass");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public T deserialize(String s, byte[] bytes) {
         if(bytes == null){
             return null;
         }

         return gson.fromJson(new String(bytes),deserializedClass);

    }

    @Override
    public void close() {

    }
}
```

`JsonSerializer.java`

```
package myapps.serializer;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.Serializer;

import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.Map;

public class JsonSerializer<T> implements Serializer<T> {

    private Gson gson = new Gson();

    @Override
    public void configure(Map<String, ?> map, boolean b) {

    }

    @Override
    public byte[] serialize(String topic, T t) {
        return gson.toJson(t).getBytes(Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    }

    @Override
    public void close() {

    }
}
```

As I mentioned, I will be getting JSON as input, the structure is like this,

{
    "RequestID":"1f6b2409",
    "Protocol":"http",
    "Host":"abc.com",
    "Method":"GET",
    "HTTPStatusCode":"200",
    "User-Agent":"curl%2f7.54.0",
}

The corresponding `Request.java` file looks like this

```
package myapps;

public final class Request {
    private String requestID;
    private String protocol;
    private String host;
    private String method;
    private int httpStatusCode;
    private String userAgent;

    public String getRequestID() {
        return requestID;
    }
    public void setRequestID(String requestID) {
        this.requestID = requestID;
    }
    public String getProtocol() {
        return protocol;
    }
    public void setProtocol(String protocol) {
        this.protocol = protocol;
    }
    public String getHost() {
        return host;
    }
    public void setHost(String host) {
        this.host = host;
    }
    public String getMethod() {
        return method;
    }
    public void setMethod(String method) {
        this.method = method;
    }
    public int getHttpStatusCode() {
        return httpStatusCode;
    }
    public void setHttpStatusCode(int httpStatusCode) {
        this.httpStatusCode = httpStatusCode;
    }
    public String getUserAgent() {
        return userAgent;
    }
    public void setUserAgent(String userAgent) {
        this.userAgent = userAgent;
    }
}
```

EDIT: when I exit from `kafka-console-consumer.sh`, it's saying `Processed a total of 0 messages`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the error indicate, a class is missing a non-argument default constructor for `Serdes$WrapperSerde`:

```
Could not find a public no-argument constructor
```

The issue is this construct:

```
Serde<Request> requestSerde = Serdes.serdeFrom(requestJsonSerializer, requestJsonDeserializer);
props.put(StreamsConfig.DEFAULT_VALUE_SERDE_CLASS_CONFIG, requestSerde.getClass().getName());
```

`Serdes.serdeFrom` return `WrapperSerde` that does not have an empty default constructor. Thus, you cannot pass it into the `StreamsConfig`. You can use `Serdes` generate like this only if you pass objects into the corresponding API calls (ie, overwrite default `Serde` for certain operators).

To make it work (ie, to be able to set the Serde in the config), you would need to implement a proper class that implement `Serde` interface.

Comment: Have implemented my own Serdes class, I got rid off this exception ```Could not find a public no-argument constructor``` but, still facing exceptions, can you help me out... have updated the question...

Comment: I think the problem is because I have initialized default constructor for `WrapperSerde` like this,

```
public WrapperSerde() {
         this.serializer = null;
         this.deserializer = null;
        }
```

Comment: Can you help me what to put instead of `null` here??? I cannot left it blank, because it's throwing error that `final` fields may not have been initialized

Comment: if you see official kafka examples here, https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/1.1.0/streams/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/examples/pageview/PageViewTypedDemo.java
they are not overriding `serdes`

Comment: Well, you would obviously pass in the serializer and deserializer you want to wrap... Ie, in your case `JsonSerializer` and `JsonDeserializer`. Compare LongSerde implementation: https://github.com/apache/kafka/blob/trunk/clients/src/main/java/org/apache/kafka/common/serialization/Serdes.java#L61

Answer (score 0):

The `requestSerde.getClass().getName()` did not work for me. I needed to provide my own `WrapperSerde` implementation in an inner class. You probably need to do the same with something like:

```
public class MySerde extends WrapperSerde<Request> {
    public MySerde () {
        super(requestJsonSerializer, requestJsonDeserializer);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of specifying in properties, add the custom serde in streams creation

```
 KStream<String, Request> source = builder.stream("streams-requests-input",Consumed.with(Serdes.String(), requestSerde));
```